# Efeito "sombra" em interior de box

Tags: html, css

Olá! 
Estava tentando fazer uma espécie de "sombra interna" numa div minha, mas não consigo. Alguém sabe?

O estilo é parecido com as box's de notícia na seção inicial do techtudo (http://www.techtudo.com.br/)

Answer (score 1):

A solução é bastante simples e pode ser observada inspecionando o elemento de referência. Trata-se de um `background` no *pseudoelemento* `:after`. Segue o código, já com uma imagem de exemplo:

```css
.exemplo {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.exemplo:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.6),rgba(0,0,0,.2) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    z-index: 1;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBWF6.jpg?s=300&g=1">
</div>
```

Comment: Eu tenho um problema quando insiro esse código. Geralmente, a imagem ela está dentro de um link, mas ao inserir o "after" ela deixa de ser "clicável" já que a camada do degradê está em cima. Como posso resolver?

Comment: O link deve vir por fora da imagem com degradê. Você poderia mostrar seu código?

Answer (score 1):

Vc resolve isso com 3 linhas de CSS... Eu não sei para qual tipo de uso vc precisa, mas a solução pode ser ainda mais simples, usando a imagem e a sombra no mesmo elemento como `background`.

Veja o exemplo. Vc vai ter dois `background`, um com a imagem e ou outro com o "degrade" da sombra por cima.

```css
.sombra {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.9),rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,.9)), url(http://placecage.com/300/300);
}
```

```html
<div class="sombra"></div>
```